# SQL : Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a SQL below, I want to select the rule fields from

- src_fotc_business_segment
- src_fotc_product
- src_reporting_unit
- src_affiliate_unit_code
- src_mi_function_code
- src_mica_code
- src_cost_centre

which its value <> 'ALL' after below filter action (e.g. after filter action, the rule_field table will only have src_fotc_product, src_reporting_unit), so I want to select src_fotc_product, src_reporting_unit from rule. But when I execute the SQL, will get Scalar subquery produced more than one element error.

```
with rule as (
  select *
  from `dataset.test_rule`
  where alloc_set = 'Corp Centre Re-Segmentation'
),
kvp as (
  select dimension, parent_name, component_name from `dataset.test_kvp`
),
fact as (
  select * from `dataset.test_source`
),
r1 as (
  select distinct src_fotc_business_segment from rule WHERE src_fotc_business_segment <> 'ALL'
),
r2 as(
  select distinct src_fotc_product from rule WHERE src_fotc_product <> 'ALL'
),
r3 as(
  select distinct src_reporting_unit from rule WHERE src_reporting_unit <> 'ALL'
),
r4 as(
  select distinct src_affiliate_unit_code from rule WHERE src_affiliate_unit_code <> 'ALL'
),
r5 as(
  select distinct src_mi_function_code from rule WHERE src_mi_function_code <> 'ALL'
),
r6 as(
  select distinct src_mica_code from rule WHERE src_mica_code <> 'ALL'
),
r7 as(
  select distinct src_cost_centre from rule WHERE src_cost_centre <> 'ALL'
),
tmp as (
  select 'fotc_business_segment' as field_name, src_fotc_business_segment as value from r1
  union all
  select 'fotc_product' as field_name, src_fotc_product as value from r2
  union all
  select 'booking_entity_identifier' as field_name, src_reporting_unit as value from r3
  union all
  select 'affiliate_chartfield_code' as field_name, src_affiliate_unit_code as value from r4
  union all
  select 'mi_function_code' as field_name, src_mi_function_code as value from r5
  union all
  select 'mica_code' as field_name, src_mica_code as value from r6
  union all
  select 'cost_centre_identifier' as field_name, src_cost_centre as value from r7
),
rule_field as (
  select distinct field_name from tmp
)
select (select * from rule_field) from rule
```

What I want is to get the value of 7 src_ fields from rule table to find the  possible values in kvp table, and then use all of those values to which can be find in fact table.
For example, in rule table, src_fotc_business_segment = GSS20006, using this condition to find in kvp table which parent_name = GSS20006 or component_name = GSS20006. and src_fotc_product = "ALL", which means all the values are valid, no need to consider this condition. and src_reporting_unit = 10080, find the same from kvp table which parent_name = 10080 or component_name = 10080... Then you might get 7 lists for each src_ field. and using those condition to fetch the records in fact table.
Currently the difficulty is that have no idea on how to handle the value is ALL columns. 
 Initially I'm not using the last select sentence. I'm using below SQL to tag my data. But as this SQL should be a generic one, so I should select all 7 src_ fields for tagging, however the data which is ALL cannot get the results from kvp table. that's the real issue I met at the moment

```
select * from fact 
where fotc_business_segment in (
  select component_name 
  from kvp 
  where 
    parent_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'fotc_business_segment') 
  or component_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'fotc_business_segment')
)
-- and fotc_product in (
--   select component_name 
--   from kvp 
--   where 
--     parent_name in (select parent_name from kvp where dimension = 'FOTC_PRODUCT') 
--   or component_name in (select component_name from kvp where dimension = 'FOTC_PRODUCT')
-- )
and mica_code in (
  select component_name 
  from kvp 
  where 
    parent_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'mica_code') 
  or component_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'mica_code')
)
and booking_entity_identifier in (
  select component_name 
  from kvp 
  where 
    parent_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'booking_entity_identifier') 
  or component_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'booking_entity_identifier')
)
and mi_function_code in (
  select component_name 
  from kvp 
  where 
    parent_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'mi_function_code') 
  or component_name in (select value from tmp where field_name = 'mi_function_code')
)
```

rule table : 
alloc_set,alloc_rule_id,alloc_rule_lvl,src_fotc_business_segment,src_fotc_product,src_reporting_unit,src_affiliate_unit_code,src_mi_function_code,src_mica_code,src_cost_centre
Corp Centre Re-Segmentation,R05,1,GSS20006,ALL,10080,ALL,RTN08630,MB20000000000,ALL
Corp Centre Re-Segmentation,R02,1,GSS20006,ALL,10080,ALL,RTN08630,MP00000000000,ALL
Corp Centre Re-Segmentation,R03,1,GSS20006,ALL,10080,ALL,RTN08630,MB10100000000,ALL
Corp Centre Re-Segmentation,R04,1,GSS20006,ALL,10080,ALL,RTN08630,MB10400000000,ALL
Corp Centre Re-Segmentation,R01,1,GSS20006,ALL,10080,ALL,RTN08630,AV1000000,ALL

kvp table : 
dimension,parent_name,component_name
FTP_BU,10010,10010
FTP_BU,10020,10020
FTP_BU,10030,10030
FTP_BU,10040,10040
FTP_BU,10050,10050
FTP_BU,10060,10060
FTP_BU,10070,10070
FTP_BU,10080,10080

fact table : 
uuid,fotc_business_segment,fotc_product,booking_entity_identifier,affiliate_chartfield_code,mi_function_code,mica_code,cost_centre_identifier
0c8d1030-a6ea-4fb9-8dc5-a7bf21f69698,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,,RTN10871,MB10112101500,580055
323e63fb-830e-4669-98a6-50738bc29f7c,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,,RTN10871,MB10112101600,580055
d1265680-5813-4c70-8e4c-85cfa103eace,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,,RTN10868,MB10112101600,580055
d6da2fef-6aa9-4d84-b6fe-e41fa2941f28,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,66040,RTN03762,MB10107051200,580054
5ca3da2a-a960-4617-b7b2-0dff430191fe,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,66040,RTN03762,MB10107051200,580054
249a5730-f758-4a22-8d35-06751b400302,GSS20006,GSP40863,10080,66040,RTN03762,MB10107051200,580054

Comment: Hi - it's not very clear, to me, what you are trying to achieve. It would probably help if you updated your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve. However... 1) "select distinct field_name from tmp" is just going to select the 7 field names you hard-coded in the previous step - so all the SQL before that seems to be pointless 2) "select (select * from rule_field) from rule" is not valid SQL - I'm guessing you are trying to replace "(select * from rule_field)" with the list of column names - if you are then you'd need to use dynamic SQL - or just list the columns

Comment: Hi Nick, I added the test data snapshots and a description for what I want to do.

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: yes removed the pic and upload some of the test data